# Why am I getting a "4 total posts awaiting review" link on PPCG Meta?

Tags: support, meta, reviewing

Whenever I visit any page here on PPCG meta, to the left of the "review" link, is a small brown rectangle with a white number 4 on it, and hovering it says "4 total posts awaiting review". The link goes to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/review, but there aren't any Meta reviews currently available. (It was showing a 3 earlier and has recently changed to 4; this is all new within the past few hours.)

I remember seeing this in the past on the main PPCG site, but only very rarely; IIRC, the usual cause was a suggested edit on one of my own posts. I know it definitely doesn't come up for Meta reviews in the usual case (I've done Meta reviews before without seeing it).

Comment: I see the same, with 4 close votes to be reviewed. EDIT: I just went through that review queue, and I'm still seeing the notification that there are 4 items requiring review.

Comment: Hmm, I've been doing some close vote reviewing recently. I wonder if it's somehow triggering on the fact that there are pending close vote reviews, but not taking into account the fact that I've voted on three of them (in the fourth, I *started* the review, so I wouldn't be able to vote on that one either), and thus can't do anything about them. If so, it's possible that something at SE changed recently to highlight Meta reviews, and it's still a bit buggy.

Comment: I had the same displayed, went to the review queue and the 4 stayed even after having reviewed some of the close votes. However, after leaving the review queue the notification disappeared as it should.

Comment: @Laikoni: It's disappeared for me now too. I wonder if your reviewing cleared it for everyone? Specifically, two of the four reviews were completed (one by you, one by Destructible Lemon). The other two are still ongoing, though.

Comment: Maybe folks over [here](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) have the answer. :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I am wondering if that page is also being cached...hmm...